# Does the size of a table affect speed when selcting a single row using the where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I may just be paranoid but I'm worried that my blog will eventually begin to run slowly by using a single table with many rows and many columns.

I have a single table for my structured blog posts which contain short numeric data as well as large chunks of text.

The columns in my table are:

```
ID . Tag . Title . Subtitle . Introduction . Paragraph01 // Paragraph10 . Notes . Photo (jpg/png) . Embed
```

So the problem is, if I use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ''` to select a single row from 10,000 rows, will this make the load time of my web page slow?

I would assume that selecting only one row from the table is faster than if you were selecting 50/100/1000/+, but im not sure.

How does the table get read? Does it search the `id` column for the row before reading the rest of the columns, or does it read all of the data before filtering out the results?

Any advice on how to make it faster if this table strucutre is a problem?

Comment: This just looks like bad design, why not create a seperate table for paragraphs and link them using a foreign key?

Comment: Well @DaCurse, I've looked at splitting the table up like that, but I figured then you've got to run several different SELECT queries to essentially get the same results

Comment: *" select a single row from 10,000 rows"* 10.000 records is like nothing, MySQL can handle in the millions or even in the billion number of records just fine when indexed..

Comment: *"I've looked at splitting the table up like that, but I figured then you've got to run several different SELECT queries to essentially get the same results "* No SQL have invented JOIN for that..

Comment: That makes it much more dynamic and nicer too look rather than having 10 columns for each paragraph, what if you decide to write a blog post with more than 10? You would change the table structure each time? SQL is all about relations.

Comment: I read that, but I was just curious as to how a table with a larger number of columns would compare against a table with only 3 to 4 columns

Comment: @DaCurse, it's not as black and white as Paragraph 1 to 10, my site has structured pages which contain specific sets of data, that's all. Not too woried about asthetics, just want to get the data stored, and read out on the web page

Comment: Well, why not do that efficiently? As mentioned you can use `JOIN` to get data from multiple tables at once.

Comment: @DaCurse - I get what you're saying, and that JOIN is a standard thing in PHP/MySQL, but essentially it's going to select the same data. You're just making the same table out of 2 or 3 sepperate ones?

Comment: @W.H. the key, nothing but the key, by the help of codd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes. Long answer, how much depends on a number of factors.

If your table has no indexes on the fields used in the WHERE clause, or the condition involves things that eliminate the use of indexes (like WHERE DATE(whenstamp) >= '20190702'), then the entire table must be scanned; meaning (ignoring overhead of sending the query, the query being parsed, and sending the result), the query time will increase linearly with table size. (1000 records will take 1000 times longer.)

However, if your WHERE condition filters on an indexed field, the amount of the table examined will generally be reduced in a logarithmic fashion. Every doubling of the table size only increases the work by a constant amount.

Comment: *" the amount of the table examined will generally be reduced in a logarithmic fashion. Every doubling of the table size only increases the work by a constant amount."* the MySQL manual has a good resource about that statement -> [Estimating Query Performance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/estimating-performance.html)

Comment: Thanks. My ID is a Primary Key, and my `Tag` is set to an index. So does this mean that if I run `SELECT * FROM table where Tag = 'X'`, only the ID and Tag columns will be read until a row with X is found?

Comment: Sort of. The index is stored separately from the table data itself. MySQL will search through the pre-sorted index for the value to identify the row(s) it needs to examine/retrieve. If you have other, non-indexed conditions in the WHERE it can then check those against the set of rows reduced by the use of the index instead of running through the whole table.

Comment: @W.H. also what Raymond just said; if "X" accounts for 90% of the table, scanning the whole table can still be faster (indexes do add some overhead).

Comment: @W.H. we can't answer that.. as we don't know how much `Tag = 'X'` matches there are in the table..  if alot matches a table scan is much faster vs multiple random disk i.o requests to do index lookup.   imagine is a disk seek is 4 ms a table would need  4ms + 80 Mb/s stream time vs 4 ms + stream time per index lookup..  imagine if you would have 50.000 matches that would mean 3+ minutes off disk seeking time..

Comment: Oh right. I've used indexes before but had no idea really how they worked. So would you say the table structure I'm looking to use would be sufficient? Or would you do it differently? I don't really want a mass of tables here, just a simple way of storing data and getting it shown on my website

Comment: *"I've used indexes before but had no idea really how they worked"* @W.H. no kidding this really helps [MySQL Internals Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/)

Comment: Yeah thanks @RaymondNijland - As pointed out in my post, I'm only looking to grab a single row from my table with this query - As the ID is a unique primary key.

Comment: @W.H. the other link was more about the internals and the under laying code.. Most likely this [Optimization and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html) is a beter read for the question..